# Unable to copy data from CSV file

Tags: python, csv, cassandra, nosql

Unable to import data into Cassandra Table / Column Family using  the 'COPY from' command.

**We tried**

```
cqlsh> copy eqdata from '/home/swiftguy/cassandra/earthquakedata/weather-data-with-uuid.csv';
Bad Request: line 1:298 no viable alternative at input ')'
Aborting import at record #0 (line 1). Previously-inserted values still present.
```

**Table details**

> create table earthquakedata (  eqtime timestamp,  Longitude float,
>   Latitude float, Depth float, Magnitude float, MagType text, NbStations
>   float, Gapv float, distance float, RMS float, Source text, EventID
>   text, Version text, id uuid, primary key (eqtime, id));

This is the  [csv file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12zlaJFd64mkHTBp5_2FHUr9cQS4WLorgyJHPYtmgDck/pubhtml) we  are trying to import

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Success using your csv data/data types: create table earthquakedata ( datetime timestamp, Latitude float, Longitude float, Depth float, Magnitude float, MagType text, NbStations float, Gap float, distance float, RMS float, Source text, EventID text, Version text, id uuid, primary key (datetime, id));
cqlsh:mykeyspace> COPY earthquakedata (datetime, latitude, longitude, depth, magnitude, magtype, nbstations, gap, distance, rms, source, eventid, version, id) FROM '/Users/krishahn/builds/2.1/apache-cassandra-2.1.0/bin/earthquakes2.csv' WITH HEADER = 'true';
2 rows imported in 0.071 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the gis.zip from http://www.datastax.com/documentation/tutorials/gis.zip with the earthquake data and compare the CSV with the CSV you're using. There's a header and commas are used as the delimiter, but essentially unaltered from the available public data. In cqlsh, do this remembering to adjust the 'path/earthquakes.csv' in the COPY command and using the default COPY options:

```
CREATE TABLE earthquakes ( 
             datetime text PRIMARY KEY, 
             latitude double, 
             longitude double, 
             depth double, 
             magnitude double, 
             magtype text, 
             nbstations int, 
             gap double, 
             distance double, 
             rms double, 
             source text, 
             eventid int 
           );
COPY earthquakes (datetime, latitude, longitude, depth, magnitude, magtype, nbstations, gap, distance, rms, source, eventid) FROM 'path/earthquakes.csv' WITH HEADER = 'true';
```

After running Brian's python script to add UUIDs, and adjusting the table for the UUID, running this command imported all the rows:

```
cqlsh:mykeyspace> COPY earthquakes (datetime, latitude, longitude, depth, magnitude, magtype, nbstations, gap, distance, rms, source, eventid,newid) FROM '/Users/krishahn/Downloads/gis/out.csv' WITH HEADER = 'true';
77037 rows imported in 2 minutes and 35.913 seconds.
```

Comment: Mine is a modified version of the earthquake data, I have appended UUID to each row of the .csv file (to uniquely identify the row). I tried the command as listed by you ...its resulting in the following error CQLSH> copy earthquakedata from '/home/swiftguy/cassandra/earthquakedata/weather-data-with-uuid.csv' with header = 'true';
Bad Request: line 1:319 no viable alternative at input ','
Aborting import at record #0 (line 1). Previously-inserted values still present.

Comment: I've seen "Previously-inserted values still present" when trying to redo an import. Delete the table and recreate it, or run TRUNCATE <tablename> to clear previously-inserted values. My command will work with my data but not with your modified data. Here's an example that uses a .csv file that includes a UUID. http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_mh1_1hs_xj__ref-copy-coleksun Perhaps it will help to compare the formatting of the example file and your file.

Comment: Another idea for solving COPY problems that has worked for me is to test importing a .csv having only a few lines of your data. Some inconsistencies in the .csv are reported but not all, I believe. Include the line of header data in the .csv and use WITH HEADER = 'true' in the COPY command to help you see problems in formatting.

Comment: Tried with header row + 1 row of data, cqlsh> copy earthquakedata (eqtime,Longitude,Latitude,Depth,Magnitude,MagType,NbStations,Gapv,distance,RMS,Source,EventID,Version,id) from '/home/swiftguy/cassandra/earthquakedata/eq-data-sample.csv' with header = 'true';
"column 'Longitude' not found"
Column Lognitude is very much there in the earthquakedata table

Comment: Maybe you can't take the error message too literally. The data types you're using in your CREATE TABLE command don't look the same as the ones I used in my CREATE TABLE statement. The timestamp instead of datetime and float instead of double. Seems worth a try for troubleshooting purposes to try using my data types.

Comment: Try adding your uuid column to a few test lines of the example data I suggested you download and then use the example earthquake table definition and copy command, altered for your uuid addition.

Comment: I tried exactly as your statement but still its the same error "column 'Longitude' not found"

Comment: Here's my test .csv containing the first two rows of the earthquakes data. I added the myuuid column to the end, e.g,
1898:06/29 18:36:00.00,52.0,172.0,0.0,7.6,ML,0,,,,AK,,62c36092-82a1-3a00-93d1-46196ee77204 and to the table definition, of course, and to the COPY command:
COPY earthquakes (datetime, latitude, longitude, depth, magnitude, magtype, nbstations, gap, distance, rms, source, eventid,newid) FROM '/Users/krishahn/builds/2.1/apache-cassandra-2.1.0/bin/earthquakes.csv' WITH HEADER = 'true';

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61132/discussion-between-catpaws-and-swift-guy).

Comment: It finally worked, the reason it was showing the error 'column Longitude' not found was .. its not accepting capital 'L' in the column name, I changed all columns to lower case and this did the trick. Thanks for your detailed explanation .. this helped in solving the problem